How do I unlock Jurassic Park III in LEGO Jurassic World?
I want to access the Jurassic Park III part of LEGO Jurassic World, but I can't find it. The boat in the Lost World takes me back to the first movie, and I can't figure it out.

Are you using the correct boat? From a thread on Trueachievements: "Fly to Lost World from the fist hub. Walk across the little pier you first land on, and it should be right there." Have you completed the story levels of the first 2 episodes?
